# sense hat sample "snake" returns "event device not found" error

Tags: hardware, sensor, hat, sense-hat

My "sense hat" sits ontop of a raspberry pi 3. I've completed the installation instructions found at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/sense-hat/

```
lexu:~> sudo apt-get update
lexu:~> sudo apt-get install sense-hat
lexu::~> cp /usr/src/sense-hat/examples ~/ -a
lexu:~> sudo reboot
```

But when I try to run the 'snake' example, I get a 'Event device not found." - error. Apparently the "joystick" can't be found/read from.
Here's the relevant c-code:

```
    evpoll.fd = open_evdev("Raspberry Pi Sense HAT Joystick");
    if (evpoll.fd < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Event device not found.\n");
            return evpoll.fd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entering **`sudo chmod 666 /dev/fd1`** fixed the problem!

```
lexu:~> sudo chmod 666 /dev/fd1
```

**Explanation:** The code examples assume that you are running either as **root** or as a user in that belongs to the group **video**. My personal user 'lexu' doesn't, so I had to change the access rights.

Comment: Would in that case `useradd -G video lexu` not be "more right"?

Comment: @Ghanima: "video" didn't make sense for a joystick, at least for me, but yes,  your solution also works.

Comment: Well, it's the group you named... therefore.

Comment: These types of problems are why they invented the device tree as an alternate way to load modules. A hat is supposed to have an eeprom the has an overlay that adds the hat to the tree in the boot loader. The tree loads modules with a "compatible" statement. It simplifies things, but this site is all about complicated. 

Comment: Thanks! Sounds interesting ... Can you provide a link to some documentation?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

the group **video** is required for the LED grid.

the group **input** is required for the joystick and causes the error mentioned above.

don't forget to relogin after usermod.